# My counter adds 1 but doesn't update properly

Tags: vb.net

This is a slot machine program. I am trying to detect how many times the user clicks a button (spins).  But I can't figure out why my counter only adding 1 to my clickLabel?  I'm sure it's a simple fix but I'm drawing a blank.

```
Public Class MainForm
Private Sub clickHereButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clickHereButton.Click
    ' simulates a slot machine

    Dim randGen As New Random
    Dim leftIndex As Integer
    Dim centerIndex As Integer
    Dim rightIndex As Integer
    Dim counter As Integer = 1

    clickHereButton.Enabled = False
    For spins As Integer = 1 To 10
        leftIndex = randGen.Next(0, 6)
        leftPictureBox.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(leftIndex)
        Me.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)

        centerIndex = randGen.Next(0, 6)
        centerPictureBox.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(centerIndex)
        Me.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)

        rightIndex = randGen.Next(0, 6)
        rightPictureBox.Image = ImageList1.Images.Item(rightIndex)
        Me.Refresh()
        System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50)
    Next spins

    If leftIndex = centerIndex AndAlso
        leftIndex = rightIndex Then
        MessageBox.Show("Congratulations!", "Winner", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)

    End If

    counter += 1
    clickLabel.Text = counter.ToString()


    clickHereButton.Enabled = True
    clickHereButton.Focus()


End Sub

Private Sub exitButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles exitButton.Click
    Me.Close()
End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: `Dim counter As Integer = 1` is declared locally in the button click event so it's always initialized at 1. If you want its value to be incremented, it needs to be declared at the Form level right under `Public Class MainForm` outside the button click event...OR...another option, you can declare locally inside the click event as `Static counter As Integer = 1` so it keeps its value.

Comment: Doh!  Thanks Chase, rookie mistake.  Got it working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening is you're always setting the `counter` to 1 everytime you click the button because it is inside the `clickHereButton_Click`. So even though you are incrementing it, at the beginning of your sub you are still setting it to 1.

```
Dim counter As Integer = 1
Private Sub clickHereButton_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles clickHereButton.Click
...
End Sub
```